# LINQ2SQL and SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Good day!

I have used LINQ2SQL with SQL Server 2005, but now I need to use it with SQL Server 2000. I have found only article on MSDN that tells about Skip() and Take() oddities on SQL Server 2000 (that's because it lacks ROW_NUMBER(), I suppose) and nothing more.

Anyway, does anybody have experience with LINQ2SQL and SQL Server 2000 combination.

P.S. Just wondering: is it possible to model LINQ2SQL class on view, not a real table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using Linq-to-SQL with SQL Server 2000, and it works - not sure about the Skip() and Take() - I didn't use those.

And yes, you can definitely also drag views from your database into the Linq-to-SQL designer - works like a charm.