# LINQ-to-SQL "unsupported data provider" error with SQL Server 2000

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2000, linqpad

I have been using LINQPad to prototype some queries against a SQL 2000 database, and thought that since I am using LINQPad's built in LINQ to SQL provider, I would be able to generate the same typed data context in a Visual Studio project.

I added a new data connection to Visual Studio Server Explorer in VS2010. It forced me to use "Microsoft SQL Server (OLE DB)" because "Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)" only works with SQL 2005 and above. Then I tried to drag tables onto my dbml surface, but I get the following message:

> The selected object(s) use an unsupported data provider

I have found a very hacky workaround by copying the TypedDataContext dll that LINQPad itself builds into the Temp folder, and also referencing LINQPad.exe itself (which is needed for the typed data context base class). But really I would rather get LINQ to SQL working properly in my project.

Am I doing something wrong or stupid (this is my first time using LINQ to SQL)? Is there a way of me generating the same typed data classes that LINQPad can? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2514093/7532) indicates that it ought to be possible.

Comment: Well out of curiosity, why are you actively developing new software using newish technologies to connect to SQL Server 2000? SQL 2000 is well out of mainstream support and the differences between it and SQL 2005+ are going to make it very cumbersome for you to develop new software consistently...

Comment: We're writing an internal tool to migrate data out of SQL server 2000 into a different system. LINQPad made it super easy to prototype all the queries we wanted to use and I didn't even know it was SQL server 2000 until I tried to make my VS project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a limitation of Visual Studio 2010. If you create the dbml in Visual Studio 2008 it connects to SQL Server 2000 with no problems and can create the LINQ to SQL typed DataContext.

Comment: This worked great, but having to find a copy of Visual Studio 2008 just to create a dbml file to use in Visual Studio 2010 is just annoying. How simple would it have been for Microsoft to leave this functionality in VS2k10, I just don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

You could duplicate the schema onto a SQL 2005/2008 box, and then use that to create the typed DataContext in VS. Once you've got the typed DataContext, you should be able to feed it a SQL 2000 connection string.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I ended up just making the typed DataContext in VS2008